# How do you adjust the repeat of a bitmap fill via actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript

On my stage I created a rectangle with a bitmap fill, such that there is exactly one repeat of the bitmap (the default). I then converted the rectangle to a Movieclip symbol, so that I could access it via actionscript. The problem: when I change the height of the rectanble via actionscript, the bitmap stretches to match. What I want is for the bitmap to maintain its repeat, such that if I double the height of the rectangle, I would see two vertical repeats of the bitmap (the way it would happen in html/CSS with background-repeat set to "repeat").

How can I achieve this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could fill the bitmap with it's max used dimensions (probably the same as the stage's area) and use masking to hide the repeating parts. Only change the mask's dimensions instead of the background's dimensions to avoid stretching.

Another way: reapply the the bitmap fill after resizing.